# Adding metadata to an audio file using cordova in ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugin-file, cordova-media-plugin

I am trying to add metadata like artist, album, etc to audio file I'm creating using cordova-plugin-media. I could not find answer for this.

There are only functions in cordova-plugin-file for getMetadata(). Nothing is mentioned regarding setMetadata() funcction.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can set and get metadata of an audio by using following plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audiometadata

This plugin has following methods to manipulate the metadata

1.audioMetaDataGetMetaData(path, callBack)
2.audioMetaDataSetTagData(input)
3.audioMetaDataRemoveTag(path)

hope it helps you.